# C# : Adding items to comboBox error

Tags: c#

I have a League.cs file which contains all the leagues for a project

when i try to display this data on a combobox it displays "App.Toolkit.Parameter" instead of the league names.

i used this code for the combo:

```
foreach (League item in League.GetAll()) { comboBox1.Items.Add(item); }
```

and the league.cs file:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace App.Toolkit.Parameter
{
    public class League : SearchParameterBase<uint>
    {
        public const uint BarclaysPremierLeague = 13;

        public const uint Bundesliga = 19;

        public const uint LigaBbva = 53;

        public const uint Ligue1 = 16;

        public const uint SerieA = 31;

        private League(string description, uint value)
        {
            Description = description;
            Value = value;
        }

        public static IEnumerable<League> GetAll()
        {
            yield return new League("Barclays Premier League", BarclaysPremierLeague);
            yield return new League("Bundesliga", Bundesliga);
            yield return new League("Liga BBVA", LigaBbva);
            yield return new League("Ligue 1", Ligue1);
            yield return new League("Serie A", SerieA);
        }
    }
}
```

thanks in adv :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set

```
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Description";
comboBox1.ValueMember = "Value";
```

That said, I would recommend to use databindungs;

```
var bs = new BindingSource(League.GetAll().ToList(), null);

comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Description";
comboBox1.ValueMember = "Value";
comboBox1.DataSource = bs;
```

This allows you

a) to access the selected leage with `bs.Current`
b) change the selected Leage with `bs.MoveNext() / bs.MoveFirst()`
c) reload your leages without modifying the combobox, just set bs.DatasSource to something else.

Less code, less errors, less headache

```
private void Init()
{
    var bs = new BindingSource(...);
    bs.AddingNew += new AddingNewEventHandler(bs_AddingNew);
}

void bs_AddingNew(object sender, AddingNewEventArgs e)
{
    string name = AskForName();
    e.NewObject = CreateLeage(name);
}
```

Now you can just call

```
bs.AddNew();
```

somewhere in your code.

Comment: tried

comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Description";

It doesnt work

Comment: Thanks a lot mate ! that worked perfect. I have one more question though. If i wanted to add say comboBox2.Items.Add("AnyItem"); how do i do this ? It doesnt accept it

Comment: You can either access the underlying datasource with `var leagues = bs.DataSource as List<League>;` and do `leagues.Add(...)` or just do `bs.Add(...)` or (and I perfer that way) use bs.AddNew() and handle the AddingNew event. I updated the example code. BindingSource is a very powerful object because it takes away much of the pain in databinding.

Comment: Sorry i am a beginner at this .. I tried the new code but now it gives the error for AskForName(); and CreateLeague();

Comment: :-) that are just "fake" methods for demonstration, you could have a textbox and a "Add" button. If you click on the button you just call AddNew() and set `var name = textBox1.Text`. I wrote `CreateLeage()` because the constructor in Leage is private and you have to add some logic to get your unique value. Normally I would just write `e.NewObject = new Leage("The name", 123)`. Basically you can do whatever you want to create a new Leage object and assign the result to e.NewObject.

Answer (score 3):

You could set the `DisplayMember` of the ComboBox:

```
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Description";
```

or you could override `ToString` in your `League` class:

```
public override string ToString()
{
 return Description;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could override the ToString method in your league class :

```
  public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.description;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It would help to over-ride the `ToString()` method.

Answer (score 0):

You added Objects to combobox and need change code to this:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace App.Toolkit.Parameter
{
public class League : SearchParameterBase<uint>
{
    public const uint BarclaysPremierLeague = 13;

    public const uint Bundesliga = 19;

    public const uint LigaBbva = 53;

    public const uint Ligue1 = 16;

    public const uint SerieA = 31;

    private League(string description, uint value)
    {
        Description = description;
        Value = value;
    }



    public static IEnumerable<League> GetAll()
    {
        yield return new League("Barclays Premier League", BarclaysPremierLeague);
        yield return new League("Bundesliga", Bundesliga);
        yield return new League("Liga BBVA", LigaBbva);
        yield return new League("Ligue 1", Ligue1);
        yield return new League("Serie A", SerieA);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Description;
    }
  }
}
```

ovveride toString() method.